# Using python to login a site using javascript and https

Tags: javascript, python, https, web

I would like to use python to login to a site that uses both javascript and https encrypted comm.
Specifically - it's this site:

https://registration.orange.co.il/he-il/login/login/?TYPE=100663297&REALMOID=06-73b4ebbc-5fd9-4b19-b3f4-42671c0df793&GUID=&SMAUTHREASON=0&METHOD=GET&SMAGENTNAME=vmwebadmin3&TARGET=-SM-http%3a%2f%2fwww1%2eorange%2eco%2eil%2fSendSMS%2f

All I wish to do is writing a python script, successfully logging in, and later on to transfer the algorithm to java.

Every solution I've tried so far, just got me back to the same login form.

Thank you all!

Comment: It's **JAVASCRIPT** not JAVA.

Answer (score 1):

Is using a browser automation tool too far off from what you're trying to do? Without knowing the exact goal this could be way off base, but what about using something like [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)? You can use Selenium from Java, Python, C#, and Ruby.

I've used Selenium to automatically log in to a private wiki and retrieve, edit, and submit changes to articles. If that's similar to what you're trying to do, it could work.

It's a pretty heavyweight approach though, since you actually have to be running a realtime browser to do the work.

Comment: Like I wrote to the previous answer - even if it would work, how will i ultimately implement this in java?

Comment: @speller Did you visit the Selenium page? There are Java, Python, Ruby and C# clients.

Answer (score 0):

You should check [spynner](http://code.google.com/p/spynner/) module, you can process javascript and https.

Comment: spynner looks great, but 2 problems: It gets stuck on windows after using the browser.load() method (probably socket doesn't return) - it happens on every website. and the second problem is that I finally want to implement the thing in java, so I wont have spynner at all. Any other suggestions?